# On styling of class components using React styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

styling components using React's styled-components.
components deals with class components.
I would like to use components (componentA) with different components (componentB) and add styles to it, but I don't know how to achieve this, so please let me know.

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ComponentA from "./componentA";
import ComponentB from "./componentB";

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <ComponentA/>
        <ComponentB/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

**componentA**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

const Icon = styled.img`
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
`;

class ComponentA extends Component  {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Icon src="hoge.png" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default styled(ComponentA)``;
```

**componentB**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ComponentA from "./ComponentA";

const RestyleComponentA = styled(ComponentA)`
  width: 360px;
  height: 120px;
`;

export default class ComponentB extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <RestyleComponentA />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Running the above code will look like the screenshot shown below.

[result of execute the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oawsM.png)

But, I want this to be like this.

[I want this to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGjFP.png)

Why is not the style I tried to overwrite affecting either component?

**That I've tried**

- Let componentA, componentB be a functional component
- Give className to "Icon element" of component A and specify style for className in styled
- Read the document of styled-components

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restyle Icon, not ComponentA. Export Icon component to be reused

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Icon from "./Icon";

const RestyleIcon = styled(Icon)`
  width: 360px;
  height: 120px;
`;

export default class ComponentB extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <RestyleIcon src="hoge.png" />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Actually there are elements other than div elements, and only the Icon element is not common to Component A and Component B.
Therefore, I do not want to write common parts other than Icon elements many times.
Should I define a new component? Or is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: Write a new component which contains common elements from both A and B and then reuse it

Comment: My problem was solved. In order to share the solution, I posted an answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From Puneet Mahendra's answer, I edited each file as follows and realized style overwrite.

If you find a mistake in the code I wrote, please let me know in the comments.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ComponentA from "./componentA";
import ComponentB from "./componentB";

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <ComponentA/>
        <ComponentB/>
    </div>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**box.js**

```
import React from "react";

class Box extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="box1">
                <div className="box2">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Box;
```

**icon.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Icon = styled.img`
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    `;

export default Icon;
```

**componentA**

```
import React from "react";
import Box from "./box";
import Icon from "./icon";

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Box>
                <Icon src="hoge.png"/>
            </Box>
        );
    }
}

export default ComponentA;
```

**componentB**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Icon from "./icon";
import Box from "./box";

const RestyledIcon = styled(Icon)`
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
`;

class ComponentB extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Box>
                <RestyledIcon src="hoge.png"/>
            </Box>
        );
    }
}

export default ComponentB;
```

Thank you very much.